# Test Service with phpunit inside symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

How can I test Services with PHPUnit using symfony? So far, I installed and included test-pack, DAMA Doctrine Bundle, and created Test Database.

Inside .env.test I added Database connection

```
# define your env variables for the test env here
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
APP_SECRET='$ecretf0rt3st'
SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=999999
PANTHER_APP_ENV=panther
PANTHER_ERROR_SCREENSHOT_DIR=./var/error-screenshots
# .env.test.local
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@db:3306/testdb?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.11&charset=utf8mb4"
```

I included inside phpunit.xml.dist the DAMA Doctrine bundle

```
<extensions>
    <extension class="DAMA\DoctrineTestBundle\PHPUnit\PHPUnitExtension"/>
</extensions>
```

Now, what I want to test is my Services (for instance CartService, ProductService etc.)

```
use App\Entity\Cart;
use App\Entity\CartItem;
use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\CartItemRepository;
use App\Repository\CartRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class CartService
{

    private CartRepository     $cartRepository;
    private ManagerRegistry    $managerRegistry;
    private CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository;
    private Security           $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security, CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository, CartRepository $cartRepository, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Get Cart by ID
     *
     * @return Cart|null
     */
    public function getCartByUserId(): ?Cart
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        return $this->cartRepository->findOneBy(['customer' => $user]);
    }

    /**
     * Show Cart and Total Price
     *
     * @return Cart|null
     */
    public function showCart(): ?Cart
    {
        $cart = $this->getCartByUserId();
        $this->calculateTotalPrice();
        return $cart;
    }
```

When I run phpunit test on CartServiceTest, I get this error:

```
1) App\Tests\CartServiceTest::testShowCart
Error: Typed property App\Tests\CartServiceTest::$cartService must not be accessed before initialization

/var/www/html/Tests/CartServiceTest.php:29
```

CartServiceTest look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Service\CartService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class CartServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private EntityManager $entityManager;
    private CartService $cartService;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->entityManager = $kernel->getContainer()
                                      ->get('doctrine')
                                      ->getManager();
    }

    public function testShowCart()
    {
        $user = 11;
        $cart = $this->cartService->getCartByUserId();
        dump($cart);


    }


    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        $this->entityManager->close();
    }

}
```

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#retrieving-services-in-the-test you can retrieve cartService once in setUp method. Don't forget to cleanup in tearDown

Comment: Could you please explain in more details? Would be nice. The second thing is, do I need to have inside my CartServiceTest ```CartRepository``` as well? Now I used the example from Symfony that you gave me, and I get as result null. But I am sure that there is Cart assigned with customer 11

Comment: First thing, you should instantiate your `cartService` property in `setUp`, sth like after `$this->entityManager = ...` you need to add `$this->cartService = ...` (retrieve from container). Second thing, maybe I'd suggest to use `#[Required]` or `#[Autowire]` attributes in `CartService` (if you're using PHP8 and Symfony5.2+ or 6+ Autowire) services like repositories, security, etc. Right now, I don't know all the details, and can suggest to keep in mind terms `symfony service container`, `autowire`, `test mocks`. Just believe that symfony gives a lot of ways to solve issue. They're different

Comment: f.e. you can just get from container (and you should if you want test real database connection) by alias or FQCN, same as entityManager. The second option: instantiate by constructor call `$this->cartService = new CartService(...);`. But in that case you should pass all the parameters to constructor and you also have at least two options: retrieve from container, or create a mock (sth like `$this->cartRepository = $this->createMock(ObjectRepository::class);`). Mock is a "dummy" object, which you able to manipulate (f.e. `$repository->expects(self::once())->method('find')->willReturn($cart);`)

Comment: And maybe in your case I'd suggest do not expect that in database something exists. Create a cart entity inside test case in `setUp`, manipulate with test methods and then remove in `tearDown`. This can also be done with mocks. Just expect for repository mock, that it would return prepared (in setup, not need to store) `$cart` entity and after cartService method run assert, that result would be same, as that object. I don't sure if I can explain well, sorry, hope you've understood the concept =)

Comment: Looks like this also wouldn't work. `$user = 11;  $cart = $this->cartService->getCartByUserId();`

Answer (score 0):

Error: Typed property App\Tests\CartServiceTest::$cartService must not be accessed before initialization

Means that you have to already Use the cartService in your application. For exemple if you already inject this service has a dependency injection in one of your controller it's okay.

But you can do better. Just create a service config for your tests "services_test.yaml" and make your service public

Something like:

```
#servies_test.yaml
services:
    App\Service\CartService:
        public: true
```